# How to make space between attribute and prior property in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to put some space between next property annotation and prior property line, it makes me really confused visually to understand which item is belong to which property with one look on it:

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

as you can see references counter makes some illusion there and you think logically current property and next annotation are a group together but they are not!

Comment: You can just introduce an empty line yourself. Or you configure the code style to your needs (go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Format) There's a large number of settings you can adjust to adapt the code style to your preferences.

Comment: yes I went there, but there is no option related to this matter unfortunately. Manually inserting New Line will fix my problem but I was wondering if VS can handle it by some option or customization

Comment: Yea, I don't find the setting as well, but I'm pretty sure it exists, as VS seems to do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Tools/Options/Text Editor/General, and increase the Line Spacing value:
[image]